# TypeError: Object function.....has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and trying to create my first module.
But i am getting an error

```
TypeError: Object function SetAstAppLog.....has no method 'on'
```

My module file contains following code :

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');
module.exports = SetAstAppLog;  
util.inherits(SetAstAppLog, EventEmitter);    

function SetAstAppLog(logFolderPath,fileNamePrefix,fileSize,logStreamObject) {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
.
.
.
.
    this.emit('objCreated');
}
```

and in app.js i am doing following things :

```
var SetAstAppLog = require('astAppLog');
var fileSize = 1024;

SetAstAppLog.on('objCreated', function () {
    console.log('an object was created');
});

SetAstAppLog.on('written', function () {
    console.log('Write operation completed.');
});

var objCommLogger = new SetAstAppLog(logFolderPath,logCommFilePrefix,fileSize,logCommMsg);
var objErrorLogger = new SetAstAppLog(logFolderPath,logErrorFilePrefix,fileSize,logErrorMsg);
```

Here, i am using node js with v0.10.21.

I am not able to find out why i am getting this error even my module file contains `EventEmitter`

Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exporting the function without calling it. You need to call it:

```
var SetAstAppLog = require('astAppLog')();
```

**Edit:** I failed to notice that you called the function lower in your script. You should be attaching the event handlers to the instances, not the constructor.

```
var objCommLogger = new SetAstAppLog(logFolderPath, logCommFilePrefix, fileSize, logCommMsg);
objCommLogger.on(...);
```

Comment: The function exported is a constructor. It's called at the end of the OPs example to create two instances. This is unlikely to work since the constructor will probably not return anything invoked that way.

Comment: @hexacyanide : Here i am facing one more issue please find question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793332/typeerror-cannot-set-property-function-of-undefined