# TypeError: Cannot set property <function> of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

Here, i am trying to construct object in javascript.
But i am getting runtime error as :

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'functWriteToLogFile' of undefined
```

My javascript object as follow :

```
function SetAstAppLog(logFolderPath,fileNamePrefix,fileSize,logStreamObject) {
.
.
.
.
    this.functWriteToLogFile = function (fileNamePrefix, message) {
        console.log("functWriteToLogFile " + message);
        var currLogStreamObject =  initLogPath(fileNamePrefix);
        console.log("********************");
        console.log(fileNamePrefix);
        console.log(filePath);
        currLogStreamObject.write(message + '\n');
        this.emit('written');
    };

    initLogPath(fileNamePrefix);// Set log path on creation of new object.
    this.emit('objCreated');
}
```

I am want to access `functWriteToLogFile` in other functions like :

```
SetAstAppLog.prototype.funcLogErrors = function (fileNamePrefix,errLevel,err,req) {
   //make new json object here then call functWriteToLogFile
   this.functWriteToLogFile(fileNamePrefix, JSON.stringify(logErrorObj));
};
```

I am not able to find out my mistake here.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

**EDIT :**

I am calling this function in following way :

```
var SetAstAppLog = require('astAppLog')();
var fileSize = 1024;


var objCommLogger = new SetAstAppLog(logFolderPath,logCommFilePrefix,fileSize,logCommMsg);
```

Comment: Can you show all of your code in a fiddle? This is odd.

Comment: This is the same issue from your other question. If the answer you received over there didn't work, ***don't accept it***. That said, the original answer you were given to that question was wrong, but has now been corrected. Your issue here was that you were using an incorrect answer.

Comment: Show the code that actually **uses** the "funcLogErrors" function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `this` is `undefined`, you must be in "strict mode". If you weren't in strict, then `this` would be the global object, and you'd have not received the error message, which wouldn't be helpful.

---

Because the value of `this` in a function is defined based on how you invoke the function, and since it seems clear that you intend for `this` to reference an that inherits from the `.prototype` of the function, you should be invoking the function using `new`.

```
var o = new SetAstAppLog(...my args...);
```

---

Given this line of code, you're invoking your module immediately.

```
var SetAstAppLog = require('astAppLog')(); // <--invoking
```

This would only be correct if `require('astAppLog')` returns a function which would then return a function.

If it simply returns the function that you ultimately want to use, then you need to remove the trailing parens.

```
var SetAstAppLog = require('astAppLog'); // <-- assigned, not invoked
```

Comment: Kindly find my updated question.Here i am calling function using new keyword.

Comment: @user2625690: You're leaving something out. If you use `new`, the value of `this` will not be `undefined`.

Comment: @user2625690: Not knowing the structure of your module, what I can determine is limited. But for some reason, you're invoking the module immediately. `var SetAstAppLog = require('astAppLog')();` Why do you have the last parens? If the module returns a function, this will invoke it, giving you the error, assuming that's the constructor func you wanted. Remove the trailing parens if you don't need to invoke it. `var SetAstAppLog = require('astAppLog') /* no parens here */;`